# Get spinner selected item on database and delete

Tags: java, android, database, android-spinner

This is my code for the **spinner** which is getting `data` from online database. The code is fine. I can't find any **spinner** that is getting a data from online database and having a `delete`. There are some, but not helpful for me because it only shows 1 `data` and hardly to understand. Can someone help me how to create a `delete` statement?

PS* I'm using an ***activity*** not a *dialog*.

PS** I'm new in **Java** having a hard time to understand

This line gets the data from the database and setting the get data to string.

```
 private void getData() {
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Config.DATA_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            JSONObject j = null;
            try {
                j = new JSONObject(response);
                result = j.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);
                getDate(result);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void getDate(JSONArray j) {
    for (int i = 0; i < j.length(); i++) {
        try {
            JSONObject json = j.getJSONObject(i);
            albay.add(json.getString(Config.TAG_DATE));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(UpdateData.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, albay));
}

private String getlocation1(int position) {
    String location1 = "";
    try {
        //Getting object of given index
        JSONObject json = result.getJSONObject(position);
        //Fetching name from that object
        location1 = json.getString(Config.TAG_LOCATION1);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return location1;
}

private String getlocation2(int position) {
    String location2 = "";
    try {
        JSONObject json = result.getJSONObject(position);
        location2 = json.getString(Config.TAG_LOCATION2);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return location2;
}
```

This is where the get data goes to the **textview**

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    //Setting the values to textviews for a selected item
    textViewLocation1.setText(getlocation1(position));
    textViewLocation2.setText(getlocation2(position));
```

This my delete code in other java class. I don't know how to call it from `onclicklistenter`. Is this code works?

```
 public boolean delete(int position) {
    try {
        albay.remove(position);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: is your spinner is showing data or not?

Comment: It's showing the data to the `textview` from what the spinner selected. I don't know how to delete data after selecting a data from the spinner.

Comment: if data come from web service you need to delete api for delete data

Comment: when you select any item from spinner just you need albay.remove(position) position of selected item

Comment: Can you do me a statement for that? and where should i put that

Comment: do this on your delete button

Comment: tell me where is delete code

Comment: I edited the post now

Comment: is there any delete button?

Comment: when you want to delete item?pls reply fast

Comment: There is. Let me explain correctly. When I choose on the spinner, the data will show in the textview. And a delete button below to delete the selected data

Comment: As of now the button is empty. I can't call the delete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just do on button click listner

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            albay.remove(spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition());
        }
    });
```

Comment: Ohh! It's working! But the problem is, it's not delete at the database. It only deletes on the spinner list

Comment: adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
also you need to call remove api where you need to pass spinner position parameter

Comment: How to delete the database when the item is deleted?

Comment: how you get the data by webservcies?

Comment: I used volley on connecting to the database

Comment: what is Config.DATA_URL?

Comment: SLR. DATA_URL is the link address to the 000webhost

Comment: and you are getting data from there am i right ? if,yes than you should make another service which delete data

Comment: Yes it is. Would you mind to give me reference? All I see in the net is SQLite it give me a hard time to understand.

Comment: are you using sqllite now?

Comment: No. I'm using 000webhost

Comment: here is the link it may be helpfull http://www.thaicreate.com/mobile/android-delete-data-in-server-via-web-service.html